# VB Date search from startdate to end date

Tags: vb.net

Hope I can get some help here.  I have the below code to filter between 2 dates.  The problem is.  It filters from start date till -end date.  Hence, when I want to run a date search for 1/1/2013, I need to do.  1/1/2013 for datetimepicker1, and 2/1/2013 for datetimepicker2.

How can I correct this?  How can I add +1 to the end date..

```
BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("FromDate >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND ToDate <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", _
                                  DateTimePicker1.Value, _
                                  DateTimePicker2.Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use datetime.addDays(1)

```
BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("FromDate >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND ToDate <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", _
                                  DateTimePicker1.Value, _
                                  DateTimePicker2.Value.addDays(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to add a day to the end date:

```
BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("FromDate >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND ToDate <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", _
                              DateTimePicker1.Value, _
                              DateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1))
```